# Is there functionality in CiviCRM for tracking the results of a fundraiser?

Tags: fundraising

In a recent fundraiser we got a group of people to sell food for a place and wrote down the orders, for who ordered them and who sold them.

Is there any sort of functionality in CiviCRM for tracking these metrics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the soft credits functionality!

https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/contributions/soft-credits/

Comment: And you can add custom soft credit types if you need!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for a custom Activity. You can create one via Admin > Customise > Activity Types.

If you need custom fields, then you can create these and add them solely to the above Activity Type (eg number of cakes, number of pies).

You can then use Reports (or Drupal Views) to construct a summary of how many such Activities, who they were assigned to, and how many cakes were ordered.

That may not quite be the recipe you are after but may point you in the right direction.